# BUG? Particles offset from emitter when using object

Tags: particles, error, emission

I'm having an issue where the emitter particles are offset from the emitter geometry.  This seems to be a problem that's happened to someone at least once before way back in 2013 here:

https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27408

I'm having the same issue.  If I use "halo" as the particle, the particles emit properly from the emitter object.  If I switch to "object" they are inexplicably offset from the emitter object.

First image is the halo's around the orange highlighted emitter object.  Second image is the particles offset in the -Z direction from the orange highlighted emitter object.  The only change I made is switching from "Halo" to "Object" in the "Render as" setting.  My particle objects are 3-vertex cones.  Nothing complicated.  None of the other settings have changed.

I'm in Blender 2.81 on Windows.

[image: Halo particles surrounding the emitter geometry.]

[image: Object particles offset from the emitter geometry in the -Z direction.]

Answer (score 1):

I kept running into this. In my case I had to:

1. Apply all offsets to both the emitter as well as all objects in my particle group
2. Set the origin to the geometry of all objects in my particle group as well as the emitter

Took me a while to figure this out